How to Accurately Adjust NetCDF Time Data to Reflect Local Solar Time Using Xarray?
I have a NetCDF dataset with a variable (let's call it s) that depends on local solar time. The current time dimension is in UTC, and the dataset has the following dimensions: lat, lon, and time (global). My goal is to adjust the time dimension so that it reflects local solar time for each longitude in the dataset.
Currently, I am using a custom approach based on predefined time zone offsets:

# Predefined time zones with longitude ranges and UTC offsets
time_zones = {
    (-180.00, -172.49): -12,
    (-172.50, -157.49): -11,
    (-157.50, -142.49): -10,
    (-142.50, -127.49): -9,
    (-127.50, -112.49): -8,
    (-112.50, -97.49): -7,
    (-97.50, -82.49): -6,
    (-82.50, -67.49): -5,
    ...
    
}

# Function to adjust time for a longitude range
@delayed
def adjust_time_for_timezone(path, lon_min, lon_max, offset, output_dir):
    with xr.open_dataset(path) as ds:
        ds_subset = ds.sel(lon=slice(lon_min, lon_max))
        ds_subset["time"] = ds_subset["time"] + pd.Timedelta(hours=offset)
        output_path = f"{output_dir}/{uuid.uuid4()}.nc"
        ds_subset.to_netcdf(output_path)
    return output_path

# Function to process all time zones for a given dataset directory
def update_timezones(data_dir, time_zones):
    netcdf_files = glob.glob(f"{data_dir}/*.nc")
    output_dir = f"{data_dir}/processed"
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
    
    tasks = []
    for file_path in netcdf_files:
        for (lon_min, lon_max), offset in time_zones.items():
            task = adjust_time_for_timezone(file_path, lon_min, lon_max, offset, output_dir)
            tasks.append(task)
    
    return tasks  # Dask tasks to be computed later


How can I improve this process to compute local solar time more
accurately for each longitude in the dataset?

Is there a better approach to handle large datasets in this context
without splitting and processing files individually? maybe a vectrorized way?


